# Android Studio: Gradle project sync failed with Java "non-zero exit value 2"

Tags: java, android, gradle

After installing Android Studio on Linux and creating the first Hello world project

I keep getting the following error:

> "Process 'command '/home/marc/Downloads/AndroidStudio/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2"

This is a fresh Android Stuido install and it is the first project.
I have read a lot on this topic but none of the solutions worked for me.

I tried:

- For more then a few hours to find a solution online (mainly Stack Overflow)
- Change AS compiler setting 'heap size' to 1024 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m
- Deleted the MyFirstApp project and started over again. Re-installed Studio
- Study the AS idea.log
- 'Run' the app, which resulted in: "Error running build: Module 'MyFirstApp' is not backed by gradle"
- Restart AS and PC
- Using multidex (even when this is just the Hello world app)

Version info:
Android Studio Build: 2.2.1
Version of Android Studio Gradle Plugin: 2.2.1
Version of Gradle: 2.14.1
Version of Java: 8 Update 101
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (AMD CPU)

Now I am out of options.

Comment: Many thanks cricket007!
although i have been hours on stackoverflow, i missed that other (duplicate) question and answer.
19:27:35 Gradle sync completed!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Java: 8 Update 101

You have that installed but you are using the JRE that in bundled with Android Studio

```
/home/marc/Downloads/AndroidStudio/android-studio/jre/bin/java
```

Update your IDE's SDK settings for the correct version of Java.